# need to display a certain list style

Tags: html, css

I need to my ul list to display the  ➢ list type instead of the default bullet type.

Is there are list type that will display it? Or can it only be displayed as a background image? What would be the best way to have that list type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such bullet in the `list-style-type` property, but fortunately, there are other ways to do so:

1. the `list-style-image` property - just specify URL to the image.
2. the `:after` or `:before` pseudoclass:

```css
li {
  list-style-type: none
}
li:before {
  content: "➢"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a default bullet type for that particular image, however, you can [add custom bullets](http://www.macworld.com/article/1048296/januarycreate.html).

Answer (score 0):

I will use this CSS:

```css
ul {
  list-style-image: url('yourlisticon.gif');
}
```